# Getting null value after date formatter

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

does anyone know why i'm getting a null date value after putting this thru my date formatter?

```
    //Sets expire date for listing to String
NSString *expireDate = [[_itemDetailArray valueForKey:@"expireDate"]description]; //returns my date correctly

NSString *formattedStringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter dateFromString:expireDate]]; //comes out null
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: How do you have initialized formatter?

Comment: NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-28800]];

Comment: Is expireDate in the format MM-dd-yyyy?

Comment: expire date is stored as an NSDate, so: 2012-12-06 05:23:34 +0000

Comment: expire date is stored in core data...then with code above i set it to a string...then put it thru the formatter into the string formattedstringdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatter's format is wrong. Try with this

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"];
```

Comment: HOLY COW that was it. I feel so stupid now. haha. Thank you very much!! I had forgot...ignored that i had got that from other code i had and didnt' update it here. Thank you again!

Comment: You can also set up `NSDateFormatter` to use system formatting depending on style you want. Take a look at `setDateStyle:` and `setTimeStyle:` methods.